# Install apache2-mod-mono-2.10

Tags: package-management, opensuse, rpm, mono, yast

I am trying to install mod-mono for apache so that I can run C# asp.net websites from my server. The project I have is a .net 4 project.

When I go into yast and select apache2-mod-mono for install it then says there is a problem that needs resolving. The problem is:

> nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIC_2.11)(64bit) needed by
>   mono-core-2.10.1-32.1.x86_64

Yast suggests the solutions are either:

> - do not install apache2-mod-mono
> - break mono-core by ignoring some of its dependencies.

I assume if I select break mono-core by breaking it dependencies that mono isn't going to work correctly anyway so this isn't really a solution.

How do I get around this issue.

I am running openSUSE 11.2 (x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [askubuntu topic on /lib/libc.so.6 missing(?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40416/why-is-lib-libc-so-6-missing). Maybe it's the same way here. Check where is `mono-core-2.10.1-32.1.x86_64` looking for `libc.so.6` and `find`, `locate` or whatever for libc.so.6.

Maybe it's already on your computer and you just need to update
ld.so.conf or create symlink.

(I assume you are on x86_64 system)